# Error 403 when try to deploy a maven project with tomcat-maven-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am trying deploy my project to tomcat7 using the Eclipse IDE, and I facing this error:

```
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Fexample
Uploaded: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Fexample (13855 KB at 61573.5 KB/sec)

[ERROR] Tomcat return http status error: 403, Reason Phrase: Forbidden
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.259s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Apr 20 09:44:18 GMT-03:00 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project example: Tomcat return http status error: 403, Reason Phrase: Forbidden: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50</h3></body></html> -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml have this configuration:

```
  <build>
  <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
              <configuration>
                  <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                  <server>TomcatServer</server>
                  <path>/example</path>
                  <username>klebermo</username>
                  <password>[password]</password>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```

My tomcat-users.xml is that:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="klebermo" password="[password]" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Anyone can point me what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the documentation mentions that the remote deployment commands should be sent to url `manager/text`, see here in [Deploy A New Application Remotely](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

by changing the configuration to that url instead, it should work:

```
<configuration>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Also Tomcat has several pre-defined roles for doing certain tasks, try adding role `manager-script`:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <user username="tomcat" password="[password]" 
       roles="admin,manager,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Ok, I did this. My current problem is that somehow when I start the tomcat (via eclipse) the file tomcat-users.xml is redefined, and the data I insert in the file are lost. When I reopen this file after I have started the tomcat, the content of the file is completely different from what I have saved.

Comment: check the `Servers` section in your explorer tree, those are the tomcat files that overwrite the server on each deployment. try to edit those directly.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the Server location configuration of the tomcat within the eclipse configuration panel.
In this way eclipse uses directly the configuration of your tomcat installation instead of the workspace metadata. After conducting all steps according to this question and similar questions and answers this step finally solved the problem for me.
Problem prerequesites: Eclipse Luna, Maven 3.1, Dynamic-Web-Project, maven-war-plugin, tomcat 7

Following picture shows the appropriate configuration which worked for me and solved the same problem of OP.

[image: Eclipse Tomcat Server Config Panel (reachable by double-click on the server name within the server view]

Answer (score 0):

The underlying cause for me was leaving out a designated "manager-script" role **user** in tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <!-- <user username="tomcatadmin" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/> -->
  <user username="tcat-gui" password="asdf" roles="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="tcat-script" password="psswrd" roles="manager-script"/>
```

So in addition to designating a manager-script role you need to create an actual manager-script user and this is the user you plug into the Web-apps POM.
My environment is IntelliJ and Maven project.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <username>tcat-script</username>
                    <password>psswrd</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Good luck!